# 502 badgateway nginx ALB redirect http to https

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an AWS application load balancer in front of two nginx instances. The application load balancer listens to port 80 and 443. What I want to do is redirect all http traffic on port 80 to https on 443. I have created two target group where group1 is nginx1 and it has the two instance and that group has port 80 while group is nginx2 and it has the same two instance and that group has port 443 as shown in picture[image]

After that I configure my load balancer to route the traffic as following

[image]

Then I configure nginx as the following

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  server {
    listen       443 ;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

First of all my targets are unhealthy even though security group are configured to listen to port 80 and 443 and when I type http://www.example.com in my browser I get 502 bad gateway response

Comment: Do you actually have SSL certificates installed on the EC2 instances? Can you add your target group configurations to your question? Specifically the target port, and health check settings for each of your target groups.

Comment: Hi Mark I found the error in my target groups thanks for the answer